# Null url in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:campus/Service/Firebase_Firestore_END.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  File _imagefile;

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  String url;


**Use This Method To get URL From Firestore**
  
void getAvatar() async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot data = await Firebase_Firestore_END.getAccData(uid) as DocumentSnapshot;
    url= data.data['Avatar'];
    print("URL:"+url);
    // return data.data['Avatar'];
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    getAvatar(); //Call Methor Here
    super.initState();

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                  Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                backgroundImage: widget._imagefile != null
                    ? FileImage(widget._imagefile)
                    **: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),//Faliled Assertion Here**
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is the problem with this code? In Hot Reload It Works but If I restart The App. The Error (url=null) occurred. Can anyone help me to find the error? I tried in so many ways but I face the same error. I don't know why it's happened. I call url setter function in

`initState()` but every times url was null during start

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to initialize `url` with

```
String url = ''
```

But I think the problem is, that the `getAvatar()` function is `async`.
This causes the code to finish without waiting for the function. Unfortunately you can not `await` inside `initState`.
Wrap the part where you set `url` in a `setState();` like this:

```
setState((){url = ...});
```

Additionally you could use something like a [placeholder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) until the image or url has been loaded.

Comment: why you edit your answer after my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change this code:

```
  String url;
```

To

```
  String url = '';
```

and also can change this one, because `async` function returns `Future<void>`

```
Future<void> getAvatar() async{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have used a single quotation mark instead of "to define and request the url
for example:

```
 setState(() {
      var productJson= json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      for(var i in productJson){
        var productIteam=product(i['product_name'], i['id'],i['price'] , i["image_url"], i['off'], i['description']);
         _items.add(productIteam);
      }
    });
```

this code true because use "" =>  `i["image_url"]`
but this code not true
i['image_url']